# Concatenate binaries then convert to int

Tags: c#

```
string middlePart = "1111";
string leftPart = "0000";
string rightPart = "0000";
```

I want to concatenate all three of these together to make `000011110000`, and convert that binary to a `int`.

The code below will not work because the number is way too big.

```
int maskingVal = Convert.ToByte((leftPart+middlePart+rightPart), 2);
```

Is there any way to do the `Convert.ToByte` on each individual part of the binary to int, and concatenate their binary equivalent to get the correct `int` value of `000011110000`.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why do you simply not do

```
var maskingVal = Convert.ToInt16((leftPart + middlePart + rightPart), 2);
```

but you can do it this way too

```
byte middlePart = Convert.ToByte("1111", 2);
byte leftPart = Convert.ToByte("0000",2);
byte rightPart = Convert.ToByte("0000",2);

var maskingVal = leftPart << 8 | middlePart << 4 | rightPart;
```

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by Adriano Repetti, you can specify base 2:

```
int maskingVal = Convert.ToInt32(leftPart+middlePart+rightPart, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string middlePart = "1111";
string leftPart = "0000";
string rightPart = "0000";

int leftVal = Convert.ToByte(leftPart, 2) * 256;
int middleVal = Convert.ToByte(middlePart, 2) * 16;
int rightVal = Convert.ToByte(rightPart, 2);

int maskingVal = leftVal + middleVal + rightVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just skip converting and calculate the value yourself.

```
string middlePart = "1111";
string leftPart = "0000";
string rightPart = "0000";

string combine = leftPart + middlePart + rightPart;

long value = 0;
for (int i = combine.Length - 1, exponent = 1; i >= 0; i--, exponent *= 2)
{
    if (combine[i] == '1')
    {
        value += exponent;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Result:

```
240
```